# What do you call the part that covers the license plate light?

Tags: honda, civic, body

My friend has a 2012 Honda Civic and the license plate light cover falls off. I searched online for replacement and I can’t find the official term for it. Does anyone know?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any dealership parts person will be able to find it by the name you gave it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the piece which has the Honda emblem in it, the only thing I'm seeing it called is [*Trim (garnish) assembly, trunk lid*](https://parts.sonshonda.com/products/Honda/2012/Civic-DX-2D-5AT/TRIM-GARNISH-ASSEMBLY--TRUNK-LID-DYNO-BLUE-PEARL-IV-DYNO-BLUE-PEARL-II/8680308/74890-TS8-A01ZH.html).

[image]

It would be part "27" or "28" on the right hand side.

Comment: I clicked on “What This Fits”. Seems like it’s for 2 door trims only

Comment: @DylanCzenski - Dunno ... You didn't put the model of the Civic in question, just said it was a Civic. Plus, you only asked "what is this called". I put the link in the answer along with the image to show you what I'm talking about, not the *exact* part number or piece you're looking for. You should be able to find the piece in question using the link and what it's called.

Comment: @paulster2 Did you ever get an answer to this? I don't think any of the answers above are correct. My son's 2012 Civic has the exact same issue - there is an opening under the single license plate light, which looks like it should have some cover/lens. I can't find any part listed anywhere. Perhaps it truly should just have an open hole?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search using The Google with the terms "2012 Honda Civic license plate light cover" returns a number of results. At the top of the list is the [PartsGeek.com](https://www.partsgeek.com/qdnr4pw-honda-civic-license-plate-light.html) option for under four dollars US.

[image: light cover]

I'm not sure why, but it references the passenger side in the description. More than one location?

Comment: That looks like the cover for the light bulb, not the cover of the whole light. The latter has a Honda logo on it

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of snooping around because strangely, for the 4 door sedan model, the trim piece isn't under the Trunk Lid category. Instead it was under [Electrical > License Light, labelled as Garnish Assy., RR. License](https://www.hondapartsnow.com/parts-list/2012-honda-civic-4dr_ex-ka-5at/license-light.html).

[image: License Light Diagram]

Annoyingly, there are different part numbers for every paint colour, so I linked the parent page that contains all of them. Basically, you're looking for 74890-TR3-A01Z_, where the last digit specifies the paint colour. It's labelled as part #5 in the diagram. Note that 74890-**TR0**-A01Z_ parts are manufactured in Japan, so they're most likely intended for the JDM/international Civic models. You can consult with your dealer to confirm the exact part number, although from my experience, they usually take a while to figure it out from their diagrams.

I believe the part number actually contains all of the clips and the emblem as well (the ones encapsulated by the hexagon-ish shape for #5), which may or may not be what you want. In these cases, there is no way to specify just the trim piece itself from Honda's parts system.